# What is the "-nolisten tcp" parameter for X

Tags: xorg, tcp

I have just found that my latest kubuntu comes preconfigured with the following:

in directory `/etc/X11/xinit` there is `xserverrc`

```
#!/bin/sh

exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@"
```

But the `-nolisten tcp` arguments are nowhere to be found on the help for X (`man X`) and we have the feeling this is causing some problems with our tools. They say cannot connect to DISPLAY, etc...

Have you ever seen this argument? What might happen if I remove the `-nolisten tcp` (ie.. will it open a normal TCP connection?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The option is there to avoid the security problems inherent in `xhost +IP`. Removing it will cause no problems but can be a security risk, it's up to you. As far as I can [tell](http://security.fnal.gov/cookbook/Xnolisten.html) the option causes the X server not to listen for incoming connections.

Answer (score 12):

The documentation for the generic X server options may be found in [`man Xserver`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/Xserver.1.html):

```
    -nolisten trans-type
                disables a transport type.  For example, TCP/IP connections can
                be disabled with -nolisten tcp.   This  option  may  be  issued
                multiple  times  to  disable  listening  to different transport
                types.
```

As mentioned this option disables any TCP/IP based access **to** the X server - which is what you generally want as X11 security is not particularly strong. It is better to tunnel X11 over ssh if you need remote applications to display on your X server (e.g. `ssh -XY remote_host xeyes` Note: the `-X` option enables X11 forwarding, and `-Y` enables trusted X11 forwarding - which is not subject to the X11 SECURITY extension controls.)