# xclock not showing (traditional X without X11 forwarding)

Tags: unix, centos, xorg

Server A -> 192.168.1.25

Server B -> 192.168.1.26

Both running Centos 6.6 with iptables off. No firewall in between.

A$echo $DISPLAY

:0.0

A$xclock

-- Able to see xclock popup on the **A** screen console

B$echo $DISPLAY

:0.0

B$xclock

-- Able to see xclock popup on the **B** screen console

=================================================================

Now i want B xclock to show on A.

A$xhost +

Access control disabled, clients can connect from any host

B$export DISPLAY=192.168.1.25:0.0

B$xclock

## Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.25:0.0

I do not want to try X11 forwarding without getting the basic correct.

Please advise.

Regards,

Noob

Comment: does the error message change when you replace `xhost +` by `xhost -`?

Comment: Crosspost - http://serverfault.com/questions/699979/xclock-not-showing-traditional-x-without-x11-forwarding

Comment: check if your X server is listening on port 6000 (i.e. not using the `-nolisten` option)

Comment: @Dmitry - the error message doesn't change when i change xhost + to xhost

Comment: @Dan - how to i check if my X server is listening on port 6000 ?

Comment: This means `xhost +` didn't actually do anything, did it? And concerning port 6000, you can check that with `netstat` or a similar tool of your choice.

Comment: `netstat -tan | grep 6000` shows nothing.  `ps -ef | grep X | grep listen` on my opensuse 13.2 shows `root      1650  1608  5 11:01 tty7     00:03:30 /usr/bin/Xorg -br :0 vt7 -nolisten tcp -seat seat0 -auth /var/lib/kdm/AuthFiles/A:0-7qsBpa`. The config file in my case is `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager`, look for nolisten or 6000 in it.

Comment: @Dmitry yeap, the xhost + or xhost - didn't help abit. The error is still there.

Comment: @Dan ps -ef | grep X | grep listen gives me this result 
[oracle@SJOAM ~]$ ps -ef | grep X | grep listen
root      2214  2210  0 Jun18 tty1     00:02:42 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit 4 -auth /var/run/gdm/auth-for-gdm-Y9ARQL/database -nolisten tcp vt1  (there is a nolisten tcp) what it means ?

I do not have a /etc/sysconfig/displaymanager in my centos 6.6

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/560532/what-is-the-nolisten-tcp-parameter-for-x. Yes, that's why it's not working. Donno how/where centos configures it, tho => big hammer approach: `find /etc -type f | xargs egrep '(6000|nolisten)' |& grep -v ^grep`

Comment: @Dan i got it up. I went to /etc/gdm/custom.conf [security]DisAllowTCP=false and reboot the server and VOILA.  OMG, I SPEND 3 DAYS DOING THIS. thank you DAN

Comment: Glad to hear. BTW, IMHO it's better from security prospective to leave this method disabled and use SSH with X11 fwding.

Comment: @Dan yeap. i am trying X11 forwarding now. It works but i dont understand how it works.  Doing a echo $DISPLAY after ssh -x ServerB shows :10.0 . It means the X server is the localhost/Server B. I will raise a separate topic tomorrow. I hope you will still be around to lend your advices. Thanks a million Dan. I am on my verge of giving up until you came!

Comment: @Dan how to i mark this question as answered ?

Comment: I added an answer. BTW, you should remove the crossposts from the other stackexchange sites.

Comment: @Dan noted dan. will do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments leading to success to an answer...

Some linux distributions (including centos) by default disable direct X access (for which the server would be listening to port 6000 + display num) by running the X server with the `-nolisten` option. Details here: [What is the "-nolisten tcp" parameter for X](https://superuser.com/questions/560532/what-is-the-nolisten-tcp-parameter-for-x)

If direct X access is desired the server's configuration (dependent on the distribution, `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` as Noob figured out for his case) can be modified to drop this option and allow the apps to display remotely as expected.

But IMHO it's more secure to use SSH with X11 forwarding instead.

Comment: Note that in Xorg 1.17 & later, `-nolisten tcp` is now the default, and just removing it won't be enough, you'll also need to explictly add `-listen tcp` as X.Org developers are pushing people to use ssh X11 forwarding instead, as they also believe it's more secure.